# Search in LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, search, where-clause

I have some code like this:

```
Function GetTypeFromTableName(ByVal _TableName As String, ByVal _DataContext As DataContext)

    Dim Mytype As Type = (From t In _DataContext.Mapping.GetTables Where t.TableName = "dbo." + _TableName Select t.RowType.Type).SingleOrDefault
    Return Mytype

End Function

Dim DBA As New LINQDataContext
_TBLName="City"
TableType = GetTypeFromTableName(_TBLName, DBA)

Dim GridQuery = From T In DBA.GetTable(TableType) Select T

If Chk.Checked Then
    CallByName(obj, "CName", CallType.Set, Txt_Name.Text)
    GridQuery = From T In DBA.GetTable(TableType) Where T Like obj
End If
```

This search does not work, and I get this error:

> {"Method 'System.Object
>   LikeObject(System.Object,
>   System.Object,
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod)'
>   has no supported translation to
>   SQL."}    System.Exception

what should i do for this filter?
vb.net linq

Answer (score 1):

where T.Contains(obj)